# Delete command is not working with cassandra CQlsh

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cqlsh

I was trying to delete some of clustering column of my table. But Even after trying number of time data still exists. Entire data remain intact.
Table is of wide row type say

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  test.mytable(
  key bigint,
  lowerbound bigint,
  upperbound bigint,
  data blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (key, lowerbound, upperbound)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (lowerbound DESC) AND caching='all' AND compact storage and 
  compaction={'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'};
```

I have checked online . But i could not found certain cases. I have checked online there is case where row key is not getting deleted but the value segment is empty. but in my case entire data remain intact as if nothing is happened delete query has been successfully executed every time and no exception coming in Cassandra.

Please suggest.

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Comment: How many nodes are in the cluster? Do they have their time in sync with each other? Are there any concurrent write processes? What is the replication factor of the test keyspace? What is your statement for delete and for insert of the data? How do you know that the data is still there? What is the select statement?

Comment: answers to @RomanTumaykin's questions are needed in order to provide some answers/ideas.  also cqlsh by default uses consistency level of one.  are you changing that before running the query?  You might also want to enable tracing with TRACING ON; in cqlsh to see how the query is being satisfied.  With just the information we've been given, my first thought is in line with Roman that your the clocks on your nodes may be out of sync.

Comment: HI i have single node Cassandra cluster. No replication. The delete query is very straight forward { delete from test.mytable where key=somekey }. and select query is {select from test.mytable where key=somekey} . When the select query is executed i can see the data. My first thought was data may be cached  so i used node tool commands for flushing. But it does not work. Did I miss something ?

Comment: HI @RomanTumaykin any comment.

Comment: @Sarkar, How was your data inserted? Was there a custom timestamp? You can try to determine what was the write time of your data by executing something like select writetime(data) from test.mytable where key=somekey. Then you can use some online converter to see what is the timestamp of that write http://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html. Is it set to the future date?